# server-migration issues : how i test my site before DNS A record transfer

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualhost, hosts-file, migration

I am doing a Server migration of virtual server (host 15+ sites ), I did all file transfer & other configuration , Now I want to test my sites before actual A record transfer , I know I have to entry in my /etc/hosts file on local computer .Can you give me what exactly i need to write in my /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your local computer  is a windows machine all you need to do is add a line for each URL you want to test that reads like:

```
IP Address  Hostname
```

for example

```
192.168.1.1  domain.com
```

Comment: thanks Sam for such a quick reply , But actually More than 15 sites are hosted on the virtual server For example Let assume my ip address is x.x.x.x and 2 site hosted on it are xyz.com and abc.com , files of both sites are saved in /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com & /var/www/vhosts/abc.com
Now please tell me what should I write in my hosts file

Comment: x.x.x.x abc.com xyz.com ...

Comment: x.x.x.x abc.com 
In this case I am getting apache default page not the site default page

Comment: @vinayrks well then that's a problem with your Apache. If typing in th hostname is getting you to the server, that is all your host file does. If Apache is not handling the host headers the way you want, then that is a differnt matter. I suggest you start a new question and post your Apache config

Comment: OK thanks Sam Cogan, Very very thanks all of you for such a quick and accurate response

Answer (score 0):

As Sam said.. it also maybe an idea to create a unique file on the new server that you can goto just to make sure the hosts file update worked.  In my experience it can take some minutes, or a new browser window, to goto the manually entered IP.